# strange redirect fail after save, undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, persistence

I have what I think is a basic create action, and the record is saved, but when I try to redirect I keep getting the error "undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass".

"Status" is a column on the record...but the record is saving to the database.  I don't know why it's not persisting.  If I change the redirect route to "root_path" with no @event params, it STILL looks for the @event class.  Even if I make the post method say JUST redirect, it fails.  I've tried removing every before action and it still looks for and doesn't find some record (that I'm not even telling it to look for!).  I've looked through the model to see if any callbacks have been misbehaving.  Its strange that the 'save' succeeds', but ANY redirect fails.

EventsController.rb

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
          format.html { redirect_to project_project_date_path(project_id: @event.project_date.project_id, id: @event.project_date_id, event_id: @event.id), notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event.project_date }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to project_project_date_path(project_id: @event.project_date.project_id, id: @event.project_date_id, event_id: @event.id), alert: 'something went wrong' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event.project_date }
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :events, only: [:create]
   resources :projects do 
        resources :project_dates, only: [:show]
   end
```

_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for @event do |f|
```

stack trace...

```
08:25:24 web.1  | 
08:25:24 web.1  | Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-29 08:25:24 -0800
08:25:24 web.1  | Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
08:25:24 web.1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3LpsRTpupzPKRWm+cNq/pxQZMhGvlXS9d35GdVRR0dK+i2ZGsRKOOeIOXzMWUEQLpLGrML2gYemeKMP2/vKwaQ==", "event"=>{"project_id"=>"1", "project_date_id"=>"11", "participant_id"=>"7", "editor_participant_id"=>"7", "category"=>"Meals", "address_id"=>"2", "status"=>"pending", "description"=>"sfsdf"}, "commit"=>"ADD "}
08:25:24 web.1  |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
08:25:24 web.1  |   Profile Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (7)
08:25:24 web.1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
08:25:24 web.1  |   ProjectDate Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "project_dates".* FROM "project_dates" WHERE "project_dates"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "project_dates"."schedule_date" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
08:25:24 web.1  |   SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("project_date_id", "project_id", "participant_id", "description", "status", "editor_participant_id", "category", "address_id", "date_start", "date_end", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["project_date_id", 11], ["project_id", 1], ["participant_id", 7], ["description", "sfsdf"], ["status", 3], ["editor_participant_id", 7], ["category", "Meals"], ["address_id", 2], ["date_start", "2016-02-02"], ["date_end", "2016-02-02"], ["created_at", "2016-01-29 16:25:24.764942"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-29 16:25:24.764942"]]
08:25:24 web.1  |   SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "project_dates" SET "events_count" = COALESCE("events_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "project_dates"."id" = $1  [["id", 11]]
08:25:24 web.1  |    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
08:25:24 web.1  | Redirected to 
08:25:24 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
08:25:24 web.1  | 
08:25:24 web.1  | NoMethodError - undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass:
08:25:24 web.1  |   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:65:in `block in redirect_to'
08:25:24 web.1  |   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
08:25:24 web.1  |   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
08:25:24 web.1  |   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
```

ProjectDatesController.rb

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project_date = ProjectDate.find(params[:id])
    @current_user_participation  = Participant.find(7)
    @event = Event.new(project_id: @project.id, project_date_id: @project_date.id )
    @project_dates = @project.project_dates
    current = @project_dates.index(@project_date)
    @next = @project_dates[current + 1] if @project_dates.length >= current + 1
    @prev = @project_dates[current - 1] if current != 0
    @first = @project_dates.first if current != 0
    @last = @project_dates.last if current + 1 < @project_dates.length
    @current = current + 1
    @events = @project_date.events
    if params[:event_id].present?
      @chosen_event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end
  end

 def project_date_params
       params.require(:project_date).permit(:id,  
          events_attributes: [:id, :project_date_id, :project_id, :participant_id, :description, :status, :editor_participant_id,
                                      :date_start, :date_end, :all_day, :repeat, :time_start, :time_end, :category, :attendees_count] )
    end
```

Comment: I do not see `status` call anywhere in your code. Also when the `@event` fails the creation why you calling its associations assuming that they will be found?

Comment: `@event` DOESN'T fail and I DON'T call status....that's my issue.  `@event ` saves....I don't know what the redirect is searching for or even how to figure it out....I tried to replace the redirect path with "root_path" and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Please add the full error trace.

Comment: can you put the stack trace and also the rest of this controller and the controller you are redirecting to?

Comment: @ruby_newbie posted it.

Comment: @ruby_newbie, I don't have that file locally...it's not in my lib...I think it's a rails file?

Comment: Lol @ruby_newbie newbie detected, lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:65 is a file from the Rails core http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation_rb.html The error is another thing

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere please join this chat room I will help you, but NOW I do not have too much time... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102016/strange-status-error

Comment: That error is telling you that you're calling `status` on nil, so my guess is you have an @event instance variable which you think is equal to an Event object but is actually nil.  The stack trace will tell you where this is happening:  look for the first line which is in your app rather than a gem.

Comment: Just for make sure, you are missing the `end` closure in your `create` action

Comment: @SsouLlesS thank you for the help, but I have to step out and can't meet you in chat

Comment: @SsouLlesS ah, that create end closure is just a bad copy paste

Comment: Also this may be caused for some `before_action` or any other callback in your controller or application controller...

Comment: @SsouLlesS yeah, I've commented out all controller before actions & model callbacks